# Using IoC advanced features with own abstraction

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, ninject

I've read many interesting articles about using IoC containers in the development. In many cases authors advise us to write your own simple wrapper which hides an interface to the read container like Ninject, Castle.Windsor, Unity etc.

The implementation of wrapper looks like this (for Ninject):

```
/// <summary>
/// Contains links for service contract and realization.
/// </summary>
public static class IoC
{
    static readonly IKernel kernel;
    static IoC()
    {
        kernel = new StandardKernel();
    }

    public static void RegisterService<T>(Type service)
    {
        kernel.Bind<T>().To(service);
    }

    public static T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return kernel.Get<T>();
    }
}
```

Okay, but how can I use advanced features with this pattern? For example I love to use life-time managment modifiers like InRequestScope() or InSingletonScope() and many containers support the same. With the pattern above I can throw away ninject and use [15-lines implementation](http://kenegozi.com/blog/2008/01/17/its-my-turn-to-build-an-ioc-container-in-15-minutes-and-33-lines). Where is the difference?

I also looked at [CommonServiceLocator](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/) trying to find rich wrapper but it has no much difference with mine IoC class. 
Now I think that I should not make my own bike and use full featured containers directly. What about you?

Comment: How often do people switch containers? Is it really that common? In any case, your classes should not depend on the container, so replacing it should be easy, abstraction or not, shouldn't it?

Comment: Normally, there is no reason to abstract your DI container away, because you should only use it in the composition root anyway. Everything else is called the [service locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx) and should be avoided.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes: FWIW I switched container in a largish live code base as recent as last week, but admit that it isn't something I do *every* week :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your application code should be completely oblivious to the existence of a DI Container, no matter which one. Instead, classes that need dependencies should request them through **Constructor Injection**, like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly IBar bar;

    public Foo(IBar bar)
    {
        if (bar == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bar");

        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // use this.bar from here...
    }
}
```

Notice how the combination of the Guard Clause and the `readonly` keyword protects the invariants of the class. From any method of the Foo class, `this.Bar` is guaranteed to be available.

All DI Containers understand this design pattern, so you can let your container of choice compose the entire application graph from the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx). From here you can use *all* the advanced features of the container without worrying that the rest of the code base becomes coupled to the container.

Comment: So, according to this I should use a wrapper for **resolving**. All the binding code (including IoC depandant pieces) should be pleced to the root and be available for modifications. Is that correct?

Comment: You don't need a wrapper for resolving either, because you only need to resolve in the Composition Root: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/09/29/TheRegisterResolveReleasePattern.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Doing some necromancy, but I think the other answers missed your point - partially.
You've been talking about "advanced features" like *scoping*. While the actual implementation does not reference the container, it is still somewhat dependent on these features. So i agree that even if the container is only used in the composition root, your implementation is probably not going to be a 100% container agnostic. If it would be, it would mean that you're re-inventing the wheel in some regards (like request scoping...)

Now, if all you need is "standard" scoping like `Singleton` and `Request` - which are supported by lots of containers - it may be worthwile to use an abstraction (custom one) so you can easily swap out containers (for example, you might want to benchmark them,...).

When you start approaching even more advanced features, like custom scopes, Ninject `.InCallScope()`, `.InNamedScope()` it's getting more and more likely that swapping containers will be too much work. So there's little use for an "abstraction", because the "abstraction" is very specific to the container.

Now you should investigate thoroughly whether "locking" into a specific DI container is worth the benefits of the advanced features.

The more specialised container features you use, the more work it will be to switch containers, probably making it uneconomical very fast. It limits your future choices. If there's no updates .. you're stuck. If it's too slow for a growing user-base .. you're stuck.

You'll have to balance independence, testability, maintainability, simplicity (... and maybe more criterias).

I don't think that someone can give you a valid answer to that without knowing your specifics. Also, experience in that regards tends to depend on one's own experience. When one has been developing frameworks, one's probably going to say "never ever". If one's been developing mid-scaled End-User applications one might say, that it was worth it.

Personally i've been using advanced features like named scope, call scope, custom scoping, ninject.extensions.Factory (+ even a more powerful custom version of it), interception, context preservation, context manipulation, conditional bindings,... a lot. And during a full 4 years of development (8 developers) no-one has regretted this. Just to say that one can be happy with it. But I'd still recommend everyone to be really careful about this decision. I'm certainly not advocating it.

One last thing. The most horrendous project i know of was one, that tried to do everything perfect, postponed it's release multiple times, and ended with a lot of spent money and not a single dime income. Creating a shitty software, making money, and then having to fix a lot of technical debt is bad. But it is a luxury problem compared to not making a single dime in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend abstracting your IOC framework. For 95% of apps there is no good reason why you would need to.

Just expose the kernel like this:

```
public static class IoC
{
     public IKernel Kernel { get { return _kernel; } }

     ... etc ...
}
```

If you're desperate to abstract away your IOC framework, then I would still have some way of accessing the real framework directly when you need to. For example, you could cast the abstracted kernel to the actual kernel. Of course you would only do this occasionally when you wanted to make use of specific features that the abstraction doesn't provide.

One thing to note about the example you posted from NInject - I would say the purpose of that static IOC class is to provide access to a singleton instance of the kernel, not to hide NInject from the application.

Comment: I don't get it. Why can't the kernel just be a local variable in the application startup method? Why do you need to expose it at all? Isn't that a bit like deliberately losing some of the benefits it gives you?

Comment: In an ideal world, yes it would be great to not touch the kernel. But if you work on any sort of large code based, or any sort of legacy platform (like ASP.NET Web Forms), then you can't just rely on doing constructor injection all the time. You need to be able to do things like Kernel.Inject(this), Kernel.Get<SomeService> etc. And you often need access to the kernel to write tests.